# Function decide where to store the pallets

Tags: anylogic

I would like to store the pallets into pallet rack "PRD6" if my typeID = 1, else I would like to store them into pallet rack "PRD7". My agent type is Pallet. I don't know how to build up the function. I'm currently learning java basics but I don't know either how to declare the variables. I read it in the help document but it doesn't help. Thank you for helping.

[image: rack_store]
[image: function_if-else]

Answer (score 1):

the correct syntax is the following:

```
agent.typeID==1 ? PRD6 : PRD7
```

but if you have lots of options, you should call a function here that returns a PalletRack and generate the if/else statement in that function

Comment: Thanks. Can I also do it with a restricted area? So if typeID==1 prd6 has a capacity of 80 either prd7 with a capacity of 40

Comment: mmm no, the restricted area would be more complicated

Comment: I attached a function where I have more than 2 pallet racks. Could you help me a little bit? There is something missing. variabledeclarators error. But don't know how to do it.

Comment: sorry my mistake, it should return a palletRack for exmaple return PRD6;

Comment: but your typeID>6 should come before typeID>3

Comment: so: if (agent.typeID <= 3) 
{ PRD6; } 
else if (agent.typeID >6)
{ PRD8; } 
else if (agent.typeID >3)
{ PRD7; } 
return PRD6;      it says: Description: Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete LocalVariableDeclaration.

Comment: no... in each if else you return the pallet rack... my friend, you need to learn AnyLogic and Java... I don't even know how you manage to survive with this

Comment: You're right, I am working on it. Thank you for your patience :)